# How to find quotient groups?

Tags: group-theory

I am struggling to understand how do quotient groups work. For example - for the quotient of real numbers (without zero) under multiplication and positive real numbers, the correct quotient should be isomorphic to Z<sub>2</sub>. Why is that? How can I find what is it isomorphic to? How does in this case the quotient group "divide" the group?

Comment: The elements of the quotient group are cost

Comment: Cosets I mean can't edit prv

Comment: What do you mean by the "quotient of real numbers (without zero) under multiplication and positive real numbers"? When quotienting a group, you need to specify the equivalence relation by which you are quotienting the group. It is not clear to me which equivalence relation you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$\phi:\Bbb R^*\to\{-1\,,\,1\}\le\Bbb C^*\;,\;\;\phi(r):=\begin{cases}\!\!-1&,\;\;r<0\\{}\\\;\,1&,\;\;r>0\end{cases}$$

Check the above is a group homomorphism, that $\;\ker\phi=\Bbb R^*_+\;$ and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for marking it as an answer so late :-) .